# Como animar o transform-scale e em seguida animar o transform-translateX, utilizando transition?

Tags: css3, animação

Eu gostaria de animar o scale e em seguida animar o translateX usando transition, isso é possível? ou eu devo obrigatoriamente utilizar animation e keyframe?

Gostaria de fazer algo parecido com isto:

```
.anima{
    transition: transform"scale" 1s, transform"translateX" 2s 1s;
}

.anima{
    transform: scale(.95) translateX(90%);
}

.anima:hover{
    transform: scale(1) translateX(80%);
}
```

Comment: Até o momento eu não encontrei uma solução, por isso eu estou usando o animation, para fazer a animação de ida e de volta.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível usar a propriedade "transition" para animar a transformação "scale" e "translateX" ao mesmo tempo. No entanto, a sintaxe que você está usando para declarar as transições não está correta. A propriedade "transition" deve ser seguida pelo nome da propriedade que deseja animar (no caso, "transform"), seguido pelo tempo de duração da animação (por exemplo, "1s") e, opcionalmente, um atraso (por exemplo, "2s 1s"). Portanto, o código correto seria algo como:

```
   .anima{
    transition: transform 1s, transform 2s 1s;
    }
    
    .anima{
    transform: scale(.95) translateX(90%);
    }
    
    .anima:hover{
    transform: scale(1) translateX(80%);
    }
```

Isso fará com que a transformação "scale" leve 1s para ser concluída e "translateX" leve 2s para ser concluída, com um atraso de 1s entre as duas.